# как с помощью peewee в SQLite изменить тип данных поля

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, миграция, peewee

помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я создала вот такой класс для таблицы в базе данных.

```py
class ProfileAdditionalField(peewee.Model):
    profile = peewee.ForeignKeyField(RpProfile, on_delete='cascade')
    item = peewee.ForeignKeyField(AdditionalField, on_delete='cascade')
    is_allowed = peewee.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        database = db
        primary_key = peewee.CompositeKey('profile', 'item')
```

Из-за пункта on_delete='cascade', когда я пыталась изменить таблицу RpProfile, удалялись все записи из таблицы ProfileAdditionalField.

```py
    playhouse_migrate.migrate(
        migrator.add_column('RpProfile', 'show_link',
                            peewee.BooleanField(default=False)),
    )
```

Я использую SQLite а в нем не работает команда migrator.alter_column_type, потому я даже не могу изменить настройку, чтобы оно перестало автоматически удаляться.
Как можно добавить новое поле в  таблицу RpProfile, чтобы ничего не удалилось?

Answer (score 1):

ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59397748/12560235
Оказалось, что достаточно отключить foreign_keys при открытии базы данных

```
peewee.SqliteDatabase(db_filename, pragmas={'foreign_keys': 0}
```

Тогда каскадное удаление не применяется. А при следующем открытии базы уже с включенными внешними ключами - они снова начинают работать.